# how to calculate the number of common integers between two sorted sets

Tags: c#

I need to count the number of integers between two sorted sets to determine if a lotto ticket is a winner. One sorted set being winningNumbers and the other ticketNumbers. I was told there is a intersect function but I cannot find a function to achieve the required results. Ideally I would like a function that returns an int representing the number of common integers between the sets.

Comment: What have you been searching for? You should end up at https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb460136.aspx fairly easily. The first example seems to fit your case.

Comment: You could at least make an effort searching Google or Stack Overflow yourself...

Answer (score 3):

Even if it's not sorted this works:

```
IEnumerable<int> winning = winningNumbers.Intersect(ticketNumbers);
int countOfWinningNumbers = winning.Count();
```

If you want to process it further it would be better to create a collection:

```
List<int> winningList = winning.ToList();
int countOfWinningNumbers = winningList.Count;
```

Since you've asked explicitly for a `SortedSet` approach, using [`SortedSet.IntersectWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412072(v=vs.110).aspx) might be more efficient(*O(n)*) but modifies the source set:

```
SortedSet<int> winningNumbers = new SortedSet<int> { 2, 3, 7 };
SortedSet<int> ticketNumbers = new SortedSet<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

ticketNumbers.IntersectWith(winningNumbers);  // now ticketNumbers contains only 2 and 3
```

Comment: That's perfect thanks for your help